# Redirect to a url when not authorised

Tags: php, symfony, authorization, symfony-2.1

I am having problems with the security in `Symfony 2.1`.

I have a firewall setup:

```
firewall:

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        query_string: ~
        access_denied_url: /register

    access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I was hoping this would redirect users to the `/register` page, but instead any secured route still tells me that **`Full authentication is required to access this resource.`**.

Could anyone steer me in the correct solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing this, but have not used `access_denied_url`. I think that's why you're getting the harsh denied page.

Using `form_login` - unauthenticated users will be directed to your `/login` route. You could render or link to a register form there, or change the `form_login: login_path` to `/register`

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/form_login.html